# sscanf %s where string could be empty

Tags: c, formatting, scanf

I am using sscanf to read through lines of a file that have very similar datasets, but may or may not contain some of the data points. This is the format of the data:
FEATURE_ID|FEATURE_NAME|FEATURE_CLASS|STATE_ALPHA|STATE_NUMERIC|COUNTY_NAME|COUNTY_NUMERIC|PRIMARY_LAT_DMS|PRIM_LONG_DMS|PRIM_LAT_DEC|PRIM_LONG_DEC|SOURCE_LAT_DMS|SOURCE_LONG_DMS|SOURCE_LAT_DEC|SOURCE_LONG_DEC|ELEV_IN_M|ELEV_IN_FT|MAP_NAME|DATE_CREATED|DATE_EDITED

which looks like this filled in:
924821|Humble Oil and Refining Number 1|Spring|NM|35|Hidalgo|023|313030N|1082532W|31.5084388|-108.4255951|**|||**|1382|4534|U Bar Ridge|03/01/1994|

or like this, depending on if those data points are there or not:
924855|Cottonwood Wash|Stream|NM|35|San Juan|045|364554N|1090003W|36.7649994|-109.0009304|**364623N|1090126W|36.7730556|-109.0238889**|1654|5426|Beclabito|03/01/1994|

My issue lies in the "||||" which is a set of delimiters that seperate data points that may or may not be there. I am trying to format my sscanf to store these data point values into a string whether or not the data point actually exists, but using the format specifiers "[^|]" and "%s" do not work. How can I go about this conditional read?

Here is my sscanf:

```
sscanf(curr, "%d|%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|%d|%[^|]|%d|%[^|]|%[^|]|%f|%f|||||%d|%d|%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|\n]", &id, name, class, state, &state_num, county, &county_num, lat, lon, &lat_dec, &lon_dec, &elev_m, &elev_f, map_name, date_created, date_edited);
```

I am currently just ignoring these values and operating as if they don't exist. How can I account for these?

EDIT/CLARIFICATION:
I need a format specifier for sscanf like %s that allows me to scan nothing. For instance, I can do sscanf("one|2", "%s|%d", str, num), but if it was sscanf("|2", "%s|%d", str, num) it throws an error, but I need it to store NULL in str.

Comment: please edit  your question and use some code/quote formatting, this is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the data in some temporary buffer.

```
// non interesting parts omitted with three dots...
char trash[256];
sscanf("...|%255s|%255s|%255s|%255s|", ... &trash, &trash, &trash, &trash, ....);
```

Or just you can suppress assignment of data with the `*` character:

```
sscanf(curr, "%d|%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|%d|%[^|]|%d|%[^|]|%[^|]|%f|%f|%*[^|]|%*[^|]|%*[^|]|%*[^|]|%d|%d|%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|\n]", &id, name, class, state, &state_num, county, &county_num, lat, lon, &lat_dec, &lon_dec, &elev_m, &elev_f, map_name, date_created, date_edited);
```

More info about scanf family functions for example available at [cppreference/fscanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: You're misinterpreting the question. OP doesn't want to throw away the scanned value. They want the scan to work if there are 0 characters scanned. But `scanf` doesn't allow data conversions to match 0 characters, so if the next character is `|`, `%[^|]|` will fail without advancing over the `|`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that with `sscanf`, at least not simply, because all the `scanf` variants require data conversions to match at least one character.

If you have `strsep` (available with glibc and most BSD C library implementations), you could use that to break the string apart into fields. (Note that `strsep`, like `strtok`, does not copy the fields. Sometimes that's convenient, but in other contexts you'll need to either copy the tokenised fields or the data buffer, or both.)

If you only have standard C library functions, use `strchr` or `strpbrk` to find each delimiter in turn, and then either overwrite the delimiter with a NUL (which is what `strsep` does) or copy the tokenised field.